# ¿Como hacer un array con java con 10 valores de tipo int y sumar solo valores positivos?

Tags: java, array, bucle-for

Necesito crear un array de tipo int con 10 valores(entre ellos positivos y negativos), y utilizar el ciclo for para mostrar qué valor hay en cada índice, y al final mostrar la sumatoria de solo valores positivos? No sé si sirva el if en ese caso no estoy seguro.

Los números que debo mostrar:  (19, -10, -30, 1, 30, 50, -50, 5, 2, 3).

El indice con el ciclo for convencional debería de quedar así:

```
0:19
1:-10
2: -30
3: 1 
4: 30
5: 50
6: -50
7: 5
8: 2
9: 3
```

La sumatoria de valores positivos es: 110.
Debo agregar este ciclo convencional para que el índice me quede así mismo:

```
for (int i=0;  i< longitud; i++){
            System.out.println(i);
```

El código que tengo es este:

```
int [] valores = {19, -10, -30, 1, 30, 50, -50, 5, 2, 3};

int positivos = 0, suma = 0;

for (int num: valores) {
    System.out.println(num);

    if (num > 0)
        suma += num;
}

System.out.println("Sumatoria de numeros positivos: " + suma);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La adaptación del ciclo for sería así:

```
    int [] valores = {19, -10, -30, 1, 30, 50, -50, 5, 2, 3};

    int positivos = 0, suma = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < valores.length; i++) {
      
        System.out.println(i + ":" + valores[i]);
    
        if (valores[i] > 0)
            suma += valores[i];
    }
    
    System.out.println("Sumatoria de numeros positivos: " + suma);
```

Cambiando la variable `num` por `valores[i]` que es su equivalente.

Comment: Excelente muchas gracias.